# Compare memory of two Visual Studio instances

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, visual-studio-2013

I have refactored some code, and now the results are very slightly different, even though the input to the method (which I refactored) seems to be the precisely same.

Now the question I have, I have one Visual Studio open with the old code, one with the new code, is there a way to compare the memory between them? I am working with images, so its not that easy to simply compare if the first 10 bytes are the same, I need to compare the first 100000 bytes, which I cannot do manually.

How can I compare two memory blocks from different Visual Studio instances?

Comment: Why don't you write the data to a file and compare the files with an hexeditor? You might also want to use the "memory window" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e.aspx

Comment: The memory window is what I am currently using. Its sort of tedious to scroll through all the memory, and while the write to file is possible, I would prefer to do it directly within, but if nothing allows me to compare memory between the two VS windows, I will do so.

Comment: Hmm, not that I know of - but you can copy&paste the hexdump from the memory window into a text editor. Maybe that's more comfortable?